# android google maps lab download map area not showing up

Tags: android, maps, offline-caching

I used to be able to enable offline caching of maps in the gmaps app on android by going to settings/more/labs/download area map. In android 2.3.6 with maps 5.4.0 the download area map does not show up at all.

Am I missing knowledge of a change? Is the feature now on by default (I could not get it to work- long tap on map does not offer to download the maps).

Thanks

Comment: OK- simple solution: for some reason I had an old version of Maps on my phone- I manually installed the v5.7 maps app and the feature is now available.

Sorry for wasting people's time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Google map can work in offline mode but mapview - not